# Why Array.Length = 1 when empty array is passed to function via ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I am having a bit of a difficulty grasping this one:

```
var data = {
    // ...
    files: $("#asgnNew-Popup .attachments-block").find(".file").length > 0 
        ? $("#asgnNew-Popup .attachments-block").find(".file").map(function() { 
            return $(this).attr("data-fileid"); 
        }).get() 
        : JSON.stringify([]),
        // ...
};
```

This is part of my `data` parameter which is passed along with `POST` type request into C# .Net controller.

```
public class Dto {
    // ...
    public int[] Files { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

All it basically translates into is either an array of ints or an empty array:

```
files: [1,2,3]
```

or

```
files: []
```

There is a slight problem with empty array. If it is specified as `[]` I get no data item `files` included in the post request. So I had to wrap it in `JSON.stringify()`.

But the strangest thing happens when I do something like this on the server:

```
postdata.Files.Length
```

I get a value of 1 returned (expecting a zero). And when I check that value:

```
postData.Files[0]
```

I get a value of 0 when I am not expecting there to be any values at all.

Can anybody shed some light what is happening here ?

Comment: Have you tried `files: null` in your `data` parameter of the request?

Comment: So if the problem is the array empty, set a null value

Comment: I did not try to pass ``null`` when there are no file. I shall do that and come back to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because of data mapping at client and server end.
**At client end:**
In [http post request](http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/01/20/sending-json.html) the data is [serialized/encoded](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to string and posted to server. Now it's server responsibility to parse these data correctly.
In case of empty array [], you are sending the string for files `'[]'` .
You may inspect the network payload/body in browser debugger.

**At server end:**
It will be mapped to the receiving data type by your .NET server framework.
In this case `files:'[]'`, it is probably getting mapped to `Files:[0]`.
This is because a particular **JSONReader** while consuming JSON stream (say `[]`) ***may*** treat it as opening and closing of an array and hence end up initiatalizing the Files to contain one element (with default integer member value 0 in c#).
Please read below links to get an idea and dig up further based on which serialization/deserialization being used at your server end.
[Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx)
[JsonReader](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#beginArray())

Comment: Very interesting answer. Some of the things you mentions I didn't even consider. I shall dig deeper into this later on and come back to you.